# Утечка памяти в MySQL Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat

При включении и выключении tomcat`a иногда выходит данная ошибка

> 24-Aug-2016 21:58:01.947 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
>
> 24-Aug-2016 21:58:01.948 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>
> ```
> java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
> java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
> com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
> ```

В папку `tomcat8/lib` jdbc connector подкидывал, не помогло. Использую 5.1.38

UPDATE: Вот например как у меня достаётся пользователь, приведу обрывки кода

Service

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.getByUsername(username);
```

DAO

```
@Override
    public User getByUsername(String username) {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        return (User)criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

По идеи я не должен закрывать `getSession` Hibernate

xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>ru.erp.models</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="500" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="40" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="1" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: скорее за все вы где-то не закрываете коннекшн поэтому трид клинапа продолжает висеть в памяти или же это баг в драйвере (что маловероятно) можете попробовать использовать другую версию или же версию от другого разработчика (если такие есть)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того как закинули `mysql-connector-java` в папку `lib`, нужно убрать его из проекта. Если используете maven, то нужно в `scope` указать `runtime`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: попробую это тоже сделать, т.е можно указать рантайм в мавене и впринципе не убирать из проекта?

Comment: Если указать runtime то maven не будет упаковывать библиотеку в war файл. И при при старте приложения tomcat не найдя её внутри проекта будет искать её в папке `lib`.

Comment: ну хотя это у меня даже било ошибку в ide. Думаю в этом не проблема. Ну вообщем надеюсь избавился от ошибки сменив datasource

Comment: Вы заменили пул соединений (заранее создаётся несколько соединений и при вызове `getConnection()` 'по быстрому' возвращается уже открытое соединение) на источник, который каждый раз будет открывать новое соединение.